# Solve two non linear polynomial equations with two variables (specific problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

I have the following two equations:

\begin{eqnarray}
y(y-x-p) = x(y+3x-3p) \\
 (p-x-y)^2 = k x y^3 
\end{eqnarray}

where $p,k$ are constants known. How do I solve this for $x,y$?
WolframAlpha provides

[this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%7B%20%20y(y-x-p)%3Dx(y%2B3x-3p),%20%20(p-x-y)%5E2%3Dkx%20y%5E3,%20(x,y)%7D)
solution.

I want to do it "by hand".

Answer (score 2):

Hint:   the first equation can be written as a quadratic in $y\,$, then solving it gives the factorization:

$$
0 = y(y-x-p) - x(y+3x-3p) = y^2 - 2 x y - 3 x^2 + 3 p x - p y = (y - 3 x) (y + x -p)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Let $P=x+y-p$, now note that the first equation can be rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray*}
y(P-2x)=x(3P-2y).
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be a doddle from here ?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Since $P$ as you define is still a function of $x$ and $y$ , this introduces one more unknown. We now would have a system of 3 equations with the three unknowns $P$, $x$, and $y$. That system does not look simpler (maybe I am wrong?) Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.....hold on....

Comment: Thanks again. Your hint was all I needed.